# Tableau: how to build cascading parameters?

Tags: tableau-api

Just see as following image

[image]

what I want to realize is, when I choose a specific area in the Area dropbox, The Block dropbox only shows the content which only belong to the selected area. How to realize that in tableau? Area and Block are both parameters.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. I still didn't have the chance to test Tableau 9.0, but a demo I watched demonstrated that functionality for filters. Meaning, when you filter Area 4, the Block filter would only show blocks in area 4 for you to further filter. Perhaps there is something like that on parameters as well. Need to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to use filter. then for the block filter,click the arrow on the top right and select "Only Relevant Values".The block filter will then refresh after you choose an area to show only the blocks related to that area.
For parameters currently the dynamic refresh feature is not present, though it is being demanded.

Comment: @liminche Cheers!.Accepting and upvoting is a good way of appreciation in Stackland!

Answer (score 0):

Filters can cascade in Tableau if you select the "Relevant Values" option on the quick filter. (see the little black triangle in the top right of the quick filter).

You may want to also put the two fields into a hierarchy to teach Tableau that Blocks are subordinate to Areas, but Tableau will try to show only relevant values even if you don't define the hierarchies explicitly. To make a hierarchy, drag fields on top of each other in the data pane on the left.

There is no concept of relevant values for parameters currently. Each has an independent range of values. Parameters are not tied to a data source.